# Exchange Web Service (EWS) Custom Filter

Tags: c#, .net, search, filter, exchangewebservices

My goal is to create a custom `SearchFilter` for EWS. I would like for example to search all emails subject with a custom algorithm (Soundex for example or something 'home made').

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
filter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Categories, myCategory)) // Standard .NET Filter
filter.Add(new MyFilter(ItemSchema.XXXX, myVariable)) // <-- A custom implementation
```

The `SearchFilter` class is public but has an internal constructor which prevent me to derive the class. Predefined search classes like `ContainsSubstring` or `IsLessThan` are sealed (and derive from `SearchFilter`).

Does anybody see a solution !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. The SearchFilter classes in the EWS Managed API ultimately have to serialize into SOAP XML that conforms to the Exchange Web Services schema. For example, a SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring serializes into a Contains XML element in the SOAP request. You can see examples of all of the Managed API classes and equivalent SOAP here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn579422(v=exchg.150).aspx.

So in order to send a filter via SOAP, it has to conform to the schema, which means it has to be one of the available filter types. There's no way to send a custom type. In order to do custom filter processing, you would need to pull the relevant data down to your client, and do the filtering there.